# Handling Button and EditText to Send an SMS

Tags: android, listview, sms

I want to handle an EditText and a button in my listView to send an sms. 
So far, the phone Numbers are entered by the user. So, I have made an adapter as the following :

```
public class ListViewStudentWithDateAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListViewStudentWithDate> {
private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<ListViewStudentWithDate> mData;
private EditText Parent_Number ;

public ListViewStudentWithDateAdapter (Context mContext, ArrayList<ListViewStudentWithDate> mData)
{
    super(mContext, R.layout.student_list_with_date_shape, mData);
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mData = mData;
}
public int getCount() {
    return mData.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                mContext.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.student_list_with_date_shape, null);
    }
    TextView Name  = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Name);
    Name.setText(mData.get(position).getStudent_name());

    TextView GRADE  = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.GRADE_ID);
    GRADE.setText(mData.get(position).getGrade_id());

    TextView CLASS  = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.CLASS_ID);
    CLASS.setText(mData.get(position).getCLass_id());

    Parent_Number  = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Father_number);

    Button Send_Father = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Send_Father);
    Send_Father.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.i("Send SMS", "");
            String phoneNo = Parent_Number.getText().toString();
            String sms = "HELLO World" ;
            try {
                // Get the default instance of the SmsManager
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo,
                        null,
                        sms,
                        null,
                        null);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Your sms has successfully sent!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Your sms has failed...",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}

 }
```

It doesn't seem to be working because it always gives me the failure message. Any idea ??

Comment: Have you declare **<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />** permission in manifest file?

Comment: What message you are getting?? Post your logs.

Comment: I gave the permission

Comment: @Clairvoyant the message in the catch " your Sms Has Failed..."

Comment: What is your logcat stacktrace. As you are printing the stackTrace also.

Comment: use `mContext` instead of `getContext()` in your toast. May be that is the problem.

Comment: to Be more specific. The problem is that the string phoneNo is always null. It does not take the numbers that are enters in the phone

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95112/discussion-between-ama989-and-clairvoyant).

Comment: Ok because you are trying to get text from parent_number EditText in your adapter getView() thats why its getting Null.

Comment: Yes. Exactly, How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're most likely getting an `IllegalArgumentException` because the number you're passing to `sendTextMessage()` is empty. `Parent_Number` is a class member, and it will retain a reference to the last instance created by a call to `getView()`, which is not necessarily the one you might currently be editing.

You need to cache the `Parent_Number` `EditText` on the `Send_Father` `Button`'s tag, and retrieve it and its text in the `onClick()` method:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    ...
    Parent_Number = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Father_number);
    Button Send_Father = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Send_Father);

    Send_Father.setTag(Parent_Number);
    Send_Father.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.i("Send SMS", "");
                EditText parent = (EditText) view.getTag();
                String phoneNo = parent.getText().toString();
                String sms = "HELLO World" ;
                try {
                    // Get the default instance of the SmsManager
                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo,
                                               null,
                                               sms,
                                               null,
                                               null);
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Your sms has successfully sent!",
                                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Your sms has failed...",
                                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check your manifest for persmission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

i think your phone number is empty there, debug it

Comment: is you sms working on single button click, if not then let me know

Comment: Yes, I have tried it in another activity which doesn't use the ListView. Yes it does work

Comment: String phoneNo = use real time testing phone number here instead of getting from edit text